# Static storage class

Tags: c

I am the beginner in C and I am currently learning Data types revised chapter. I have solved many programs of static storage class. Static storage class has a local scope. In the below code the static variable is declared above main i.e global variable. Is this possible ? And the o/p according to features of static storage class is correct.

```
static int y ;
main( )
{
static int z ;
printf ("%d %d", y, z ) ;
}
```

Can anyone please let me know that the declaration of static variable above main is correct ? If this is correct please try to explain in layman language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storage class and scope are different things. The `static` keyword does not affect scope.

Storage class is related to the lifetime or storage duration of an object: When it is created and when its lifetime ends. Unfortunately, there is some mixing of storage class and other concepts, due to historical reasons. Storage class has some connotations about **where** something is stored. C has evolved so that the decision about where something is stored is largely up to the implementation. Usually, the programmer should only care about **when** something is stored.

Storage class is a property of an object: The actual thing (value) being stored. Scope is a property of an identifier: The name used to refer to an object (or a type or a function).

There are four storage durations: static, thread, automatic, and allocated. There are four kinds of scopes: function, file, block, and function prototype. The rules for them are somewhat complicated (and also depend on linkage, which can be external, internal, or none), so I will not describe them all.

If you define an object to be `static`, its lifetime is the entire execution of the program. By default, an ordinary object declared inside a function body has automatic storage duration. Its lifetime is from the time program execution enters the block it is in until program execution exits the block it is in. Each time execution enters the block, a new instance of the object is created. As you can see, lifetime is a property that applies when a program is running.

When you declare an object inside a function body, the identifier (name) in the declaration has block scope. The name is only visible inside the block. Scope is a compile-time property; it affects what parts of the source code can see the name. For example, if your function A calls function B at run-time, function B cannot see the names inside function A. Even though the objects in function A exist (a run-time property) while function B executes, their names (a compile-time property) are not visible in function B.

A name inside a function body has block scope, but it can refer to an object with automatic (block) storage duration or to an object with static (entire program) storage duration.

When you declare an object outside a function body, its identifier has file scope. It is visible to all following source code in the file.

There is also a property called linkage. Linkage is a method by which the same identifier in different scopes can be made to refer to the same object. (The `foo` in one source file can be made to refer to the same object is the `foo` of another source file.)

Comment: Asterisk - `static` effects external scope (other files), but not internal (current file0. Very important to note that.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's called *linkage* of identifiers, not scope.

Comment: @Jens of course it is related to the linkage, but it is entirely possible to have C that isn't linked (ran as a script), thus making it *external* scope more technically.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The C Standard clearly defines the concept of scope in C99 6.2.1; there is no such thing as external scope. There is, however, external linkage for static variables and that's exactly what happens here. Even a C interpreter would have to behave accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

`y` is a global variable, but since it is declared `static`, it is only visible in the compilation unit, i.e. this same C-file. It will not be accessible from other units if you are compiling multiple objects and linking them together.
In this simple example it is not relevant whether a global variable is declared static.